# Check field type and execute depending on it using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I had a script that converted data from a clients site to a usable GIS format until they changed the output.  I've tried two different directions with no luck.  Due to how an earlier part of the script works, CSV to Table, and the nature of the data being converted; the 'total_length' field that's imported might end up being a string or an integer (TableToTable conversion will not work).  I need it to look at the field type and if it's already an integer then populate the 'length_val' field with the number.  If it's a string then strip it down to the number (typically the greater than, less than or tilde off the front) and populate the 'length_val' field.

In other words:
If 'total_length' = STRING, then send only the number to 'length_val'
Otherwise, if 'total_length' = INTEGER, then calculate the field.

I've been using update cursors to do a lot of the rest of the work, but that doesn't have to be the case.

```
Row[3] = 'total_length'
Row[17] = 'length_val'


#---First Attempt---

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(aoi_table_gdb,aoi_fields) as cursor:
    totlen = "total_length"  #<--- This was just an idea
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(aoi_table_gdb)
    for field in fields:
        if field.name = '"'+ totlen +'"' and field.type = String:
            for row in cursor:
                if row[3] == None:
                    row[17] = None
                elif row[3].find(str('~ ')) > -1:
                    row[17] = row[3].lstrip(str('~ '))
                elif row[3].find(str('> ')) > -1:
                    row[17] = row[3].lstrip(str('> '))
                elif row[3].find(str('< ')) > -1:
                    row[17] = row[3].lstrip(str('< '))
                else:
                    row[17] = row[3]
        else:
            for row in cursor:
                row[17] = row[3]
        cursor.updateRow(row)




#---Second Attempt---

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(aoi_table_gdb,aoi_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #Length Value
        if row[3] == None:
            row[17] = None
            arcpy.AddWarning("A. Row: " + str(row[1]) + " - " + str(row[3]))
        elif row[3].isdigit():
            row[17] = row[3]
            arcpy.AddWarning("B. Row: " + str(row[1]) + " - " + str(row[3]))
        else:
            length = filter(unicode.isdigit, row[3])
            row[17] = length
            arcpy.AddWarning("C. Row: " + str(row[1]) + " - " + str(row[3]))
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that your first approach has the right idea, but needs to be reordered somewhat.

- You do not need to check the field name/type *on each cursor loop*, but only once before executing the cursor.
- You don't need to get all the fields with your UpdateCursor, just the two you are interested in (the field providing the data, and the field you're calculating into).

So something more like the following (without the conditional to calculate in the case of it not being a string yet)

```
fields = arcpy.ListFields(aoi_table_gdb)
for field in fields:
    if field.name == 'total_length' and field.type == 'String':
        lengthIsString = True
    elif field.name == 'total_length' and not field.type == 'String':
        lengthIsString = False

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(aoi_table_gdb, ["total_length", "length_val"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if lengthIsString:
            row[1] = # conditional to count the string
        else:
            row[1] = row[0]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```